# Can I use select to combine stdin and accept?

Tags: c++, select, pthreads

I am trying to implement a server in C++/Linux that regularly takes user input from the terminal. Initially I had implemented two separate threads to handle this behavior. But I realized that I would need something like pthread_cancel to cancel the server thread in case the user wanted to shut down the server.

I then decided that it might be better to handle both actions in the same thread, so I dont have to worry about resource leakage. So what I have now is a 'select' call that selects over the stdin fd as well as my accepting fd. My code looks something like this...

```
fdset readfds;
FD_SET(acceptfd, &readfds);
FD_SET(stdinfd, &readfds);
while(1) {
  select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  ....
}
```

For some reason I am no longer able to read input from stdin. This works fine when I remove either one of the two fds from my fd set, the other ome performs as expected. But when I leave them both in, while the acceptfd still accepts incoming connections, the stdinfd fails to respond to terminal input.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? Is this approach inherently flawed? Should I be focusing on keeping the two actions as separate threads and figuring out a way to exit cleanly instead?

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: It definitely is possible to muliplex stdin and a listen fd. What exactly is happening? Insert some printf's in between to see. It's likely that you've forgotten to put the the file descriptors to non-blocking mode, and your read() or accept() blocks instead of returning immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ambroz commented, multiplexing stdin and some listened fd is possible.

But `select` is an old, nearly obsolete syscall, you should prefer using [`poll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html). If you insist on still using `select(2)` syscall, you should clear the `readfds` at first with `FD_ZERO` inside the loop. And the `FD_SET` macros should be inside the while loop, because `select` is permitted to modify the `readfds`.

The `poll` syscall is preferable to `select` because `select` impose a wired-in limit to the number of file descriptors the process can have (typically 1024, while the kernel is today able to deal with a bigger number of fds, eg 65536). In other words, `select` requires that every fd is < 1024 (which is false today). `poll` is able to deal with any set of any fd. The first argument to `poll` is an array (which you could `calloc` if you wanted to) whose size is the number of fds you want to multiplex. In your case, it is two (stdin and the second listened fd), so you can make it a local variable. Be sure to clear and initialize it before every call to `poll`.

You could debug with a debugger like `gdb` or just use `strace`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies. I will certainly consider using poll. From what I understand, in order to work with poll, I need to statically know the size of my polling set. Is this correct? That is why I use select instead, where I can dynamically figure out which fds I want to add to my set.

I think this may well be an issue of my sockets still being in blocking mode. Would you suggest making both of them non-blocking? I tried that and it didnt seem to have an effect but I will continue to look for reasons why. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, problem solved! I needed to have my code inside the while loop. Took 2 hours of my life that I'll never get back. :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This [`epoll`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html) code works for me:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4711

int main(void) {
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof (addr));
    listen(sockfd, 10);

    int epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
    struct epoll_event event;
    // add stdin
    event.events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLPRI|EPOLLERR;
    event.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &event) != 0) {
        perror("epoll_ctr add stdin failed.");
        return 1;
    }
    // add socket
    event.events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLPRI|EPOLLERR;
    event.data.fd = sockfd;
    if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd, &event) != 0) {
        perror("epoll_ctr add sockfd failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linelen = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int fds = epoll_wait(epollfd, &event, 1, -1);
        if (fds < 0) {
            perror("epoll_wait failed.");
            return 2;
        }
        if (fds == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (event.data.fd == STDIN_FILENO) {
            // read input line
            int read = getline(&line, &linelen, stdin);
            if (read < 0) {
                perror("could not getline");
                return 3;
            }
            printf("Read: %.*s", read, line);
        } else if (event.data.fd == sockfd) {
            // accept client
            struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
            socklen_t addrlen = sizeof (client_addr);
            int clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &addrlen);
            if (clientfd == -1) {
                perror("could not accept");
                return 4;
            }
            send(clientfd, "Bye", 3, 0);
            close(clientfd);
        } else {
            // cannot happen™
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad fd: %d\n", event.data.fd);
            return 5;
        }
    }

    close(epollfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}
```