# Periodic Task in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer

I want to write a C program that would periodically perform some task (say, print something on console).

I have implemented it using nanosleep as below. Every 500ms the function 'func' is called.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void func(void);

int main()
{
  struct timespec mytimespec;
  mytimespec.tv_sec = 0;
  mytimespec.tv_nsec = 500000000; /* 500 ms */

  while(1)
  {
    func(); 
    nanosleep(&mytimespec,NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}

void func(void)
{
  printf("This would be printed periodically\n");
}
```

Above is working correctly. However I have some doubts:-

- Would it work accurately if there are multiple threads and one thread relies on `nanosleep` to do the periodic task?
- Is there a way to spawn a periodic thread in linux? Or, to use some timer callback?

Comment: Why not use Cron? http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Comment: @Ed Heal: Thanks. Actually I want to learn the C/C++ way of doing it.

Comment: @Siddhartha Ghosh you should specify the nature of this threads, cause mechanism should be determined by task.

Comment: @EdHeal `cron` works on minute boundaries at best, nowhere close to every 500ms...

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup - Then just do a sleep before doing any work.

Comment: @EdHeal I don't disagree that it *could* work, but getting `cron` to trigger a job *every* 500ms is not a good solution, nor a good answer to this question.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup - It was not an answer to the question (using comments is the giveaway). Anyway just run the program continuously and pause once in a while

Comment: @EdHeal The fact that it's a comment doesn't make it better or more relevant to the question.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup - Perhaps it is and perhaps it is not. Not for me nor you to comment. That is the point of giving a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) (and perhaps [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)...). You probably want some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (at least if your program is doing some input). That loop is based upon a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704858/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19151385/841108) answers). Many libraries provide event loops, notably [libevent](http://libevent.org/), [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), Gtk/Glib, Qt, ...

On Linux you could be *also* interested by [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) (in addition of other more traditional solutions).

And read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 2):

timer_create will be the system call you are looking for.

it has a sigaction structure that specify what way the callback should be called.

you have to initialize the member it_interval in the timer_settime function's newvalue argument, so that the function that registered at sigaction structure is called every it_interval.

the function can be a signal handler, a thread that will be run when the timer is expired.

see timer_create manual page for more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it work accurately if there are multiple threads and one thread relies on nanosleep to do the periodic task?

Function `nanosleep()` won't return earlier than you've specified in its arguments (unless it is interrupted by signal handler or encounters an error). But it may return later (usually only a bit later).

Please, take a look on the following article: 
http://www.drdobbs.com/soft-real-time-programming-with-linux/184402031 - it seems to explain timers in a good way.

> Is there a way to spawn a periodic thread in linux? Or, to use some timer callback?

Take a look on timers: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Comment: "Function nanosleep() won't return earlier than you've specified in its arguments. But it may return later (usually a bit)." That's not true - it can be interrupted by a signal.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways depending on task:

1) You can use realtime clock (man rtc)

2) You can use cron (spawning processes any process by timer)

3) You can use select/pselect (it is good for small time intervals for periodic thread spawning)

```
/* Wait up to five seconds. */
           tv.tv_sec = 5;
           tv.tv_usec = 0;

           retval = select(1, 0, 0, 0, &tv);
```

And if you are monitoring files/directories you can use inotify.

Comment: Is 'select' a blocking call? Will it eat CPU when it is waiting?

Comment: @ Siddhartha Ghosh O_O - of course it won't eat anything it blockes until file descriptors become ready or in our case until timeout or if interrupted by a signal (this can be avoided by blocking signals), see man pselect.

Comment: I suggest using `poll`, not `select`. Google about the `C10K problem`.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch For what? How timeout related to network connections?

Comment: The point is that `sizeof(fd_set)` is builtin inside Glibc, to a quite small value. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11704858/841108) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19151385/841108) answers.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - i know. Again - i don't care for massive connect in this example fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds are zero - we are using a TIMEOUT.