# How to wait for time to expire

Tags: c, timer, virtual

I would like to have a function run periodically, given a time step. What is the most efficient way to do this?

I know I could use a while look and just keep checking till the dt period has elapsed. But I'd like to know if there is a better, more efficient/elegant function to use.

I was looking into virtual timers and sigaction. Using this method, I would have the sigaction handler set a flag when the time has elapsed, but I would still need to sit in a while loop checking for that flag to be set in my main function. Alternatively I wonder if I could actually have the handler run the function, but then I would have to pass a lot of arguments, and as far as I have read, handlers don't take arguments, so I would have to use lots of global variables.

What would be the best way to tackled this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19447667/841108) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an *IX'ish system you could

- install a handler for `SIGALRM`, which does nothing
- set an alarm using `alarm()`
- call blocking `pause()`

If the alarm signal is sent `pause()` will return and

- you can run the function in question,
- again set the alarm
- start over calling `pause()`

---

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

void handler_SIGALRM(int signo)
{
  signo = 0; /* Get rid of warning "unused parameter ‘signo’" (in a portable way). */

  /* Do nothing. */
}

int main()
{
  /* Override SIGALRM's default handler, as the default handler might end the program. */
  {
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

    sa.sa_handler = handler_SIGALRM;

    if (-1 == sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL ))
    {
      perror("sigaction() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  while (1)
  {
     alarm(2); /* Set alarm to occur in two seconds. */

     pause(); /* The call blocks until a signal is received; in theis case typically SIGARLM. */

     /* Do what is to be done every 2 seconds. */
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `sleep` or `usleep` as defined in `unistd.h`.

If neither of those are available then a common workaround is to use a `select` with a timeout on no file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Include time.h and use sleep function like

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<windows.h> 
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    printf("I am going to wait for 4 sec");
    Sleep(4000); //sleep for 4000 microsecond= 4 second
    printf("Finaaly the wait is over");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It will give you a precise delay on microsecond level.
Hope it helped.